# how to group and sum the query result

Tags: sql-server

I want to have the query result look like this:

```
Product Desc     Site 1     Site 2     Site 3     Site 4

Product A        100        200        300        400
Product B         50         60         70         80
```

My table looks like this

```
Site ProductCode Amount

1    A            10.00
1    B            20.00
2    B            30.00
3    A            40.00
3    A            50.00
4    B            60.00
4    B            70.00
```

How will I build my sql query?

Comment: could you please provide more information. You could give us a script to recreate your table and some data in it for example. That will be easier for us to help you that way.
Also, if you could clarify your output (with some printscreen for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pivot query to do this, maybe construct it using dynamic SQL if that's potentially a requirement.

```
IF ( OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb.dbo.#t_Sample', 'U' ) IS NULL )
BEGIN
    --DROP TABLE #t_Sample;
    CREATE TABLE #t_Sample
    (
        [Site]              INTEGER,
        ProductCode         CHAR( 1 ),
        Amount              DECIMAL( 4, 2 )
    );

    INSERT  INTO #t_Sample ( [Site], ProductCode, Amount )
                SELECT  1, 'A', 10.00
    UNION ALL   SELECT  1, 'B', 20.00
    UNION ALL   SELECT  2, 'B', 30.00
    UNION ALL   SELECT  3, 'A', 40.00
    UNION ALL   SELECT  3, 'A', 50.00
    UNION ALL   SELECT  4, 'B', 60.00
    UNION ALL   SELECT  4, 'B', 70.00;
END;
GO

SELECT  ProductDesc = 'Product ' + p.ProductCode,
        [Site 1] = ISNULL( p.[1], 0.00 ),
        [Site 2] = ISNULL( p.[2], 0.00 ),
        [Site 3] = ISNULL( p.[3], 0.00 ),
        [Site 4] = ISNULL( p.[4], 0.00 )
FROM (  SELECT  [Site], ProductCode, Amount
        FROM    #t_Sample ) s
PIVOT ( SUM( Amount )
        FOR [Site] IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4] ) ) p
```